# If an old C++ compiler doesn't implement a new keyword, is it wrong to define it away?

Tags: c++

I am maintaining a library that is still supported on older compilers, one of which is Visual C++ 2013 on Windows.  So far we've been extremely conservative and stuck to C++03; we're now moving to C++11.  VC++2013 supports most of the newer features, but it doesn't recognize `noexcept`.

Of course the canonical way to add it to the code would be to define something like

```cpp
#if (the compiler does not support it)
    #define NOEXCEPT
#else
    #define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#endif
```

and then use it like

```cpp
void f() NOEXCEPT;
```

The downside, of course, is that we're sprinkling macros around the code.

However, it occurred to me (possibly suggested by a little guardian devil on my shoulder) that I could also write

```cpp
#if (the compiler does not support it)
    #define noexcept
#endif
```

after which I could write

```
void f() noexcept;
```

and the keyword would be used correctly by newer compilers and defined away on the older ones.

This worked (as in, it compiled successfully) but, well, I'm feeling kind of dirty — and I'm not sure I should.  Of course, defining away a keyword is forbidden under the standard that defines it; but is it still so if the compiler doesn't fully support the standard, or am I in some kind of grey area?

Comment: The first is acceptable, the second is evil :D

Comment: I'm afraid C++03 (or, in fact C++98) is almost as much apart from modern C++17, let alone C++20, as C is. If I were to keep a library for both C && C++, I would stick to C and would not introduce a single dot from the C++ specification. I guess if you want to maintain the ability co compile using C++03, you should forget about introducing anything from C++11 or later versions.  Anyway, you will never use lambdas, variadic templates, multithreadnig etc., so there seems to be little point in introducing just `noexcept` and  perhaps other little things like this.

Comment: To answer your question: I would prefer `NOEXCEPT` to `noexcept` just to stress that the software is written in C++03 and `NOEXCEPT` is there only to take advantage of newer compilers, if there are any.  In other words, the software should look natural for someone who could see it back in  2003.

Comment: @zkoza sorry, I didn't make myself clear. We're starting to migrate to C++11, and I'd like to keep support (at least for a while) for VC++2013, which supports most of it but not `noexcept`.  Thanks for the comment: I'll edit the question for clarity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it wasn't a keyword in the old standards, you were, and technically still are allowed to define such macro when targeting the old standard.

P.S. The typical definition for pre-C++11 is to use `throw()` in place of `noexcept`.

P.P.S. Note that in the case of `noexcept`, the macro doesn't work for declarations such as

```
void foo() noexcept(false);
bool bar = noexcept(foo());
```

So, these statements cannot be so easily made backwards compatible. Given the inability to support all use cases of `noexcept`, the usage of different name for the macro may help to avoid confusion.

Comment: You're right, I completely overlooked the version taking a boolean.  Macro it is, then.